DB_CHARSET/DB_COLLATE issue
Need some advice about DB_CHARSET and DB_COLLATE. I’ve been using WordPress for years with define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); set in my wp-config. Recently I needed to display latin1 characters and so modified this to:
define('DB_CHARSET', 'latin1');
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci');

This fixed my problem but unfortunately I now have characters in old posts (such as em dashes —) that display as question mark/diamond characters. If I'm understanding what I'm reading here (https://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets) I should leave DB_CHARSET as utf8 but how do I fix the original issue of being able to post latin1 and display it correctly?

No simple answer.  Those two defines conflict with each other.  For starters into debugging, please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table that contains an em dash.
